# JSF2 Value is not valid when submitting zero

Tags: validation, jsf-2.2

I have read many posts about this JSF2 validation error, but cannot see why this is occurring.
My select items are a List where ListItem is a POJO with two String fields, key, and value.  When I submit the page choosing a select item option with a value of "0", I get the following error: Validation Error: Value is not valid.

The value to be submitted is bound to an int. Here is the equals method in ListItem, but I have a debug point on this method and it doesn't appear to get hit, so I can't see if this is the issue:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if (other == null || !(other instanceof ListItem))
        return false;
    ListItem otherLI = (ListItem) other;
    return otherLI.key.equals(key);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have fixed it after doing some debugging in the UISelectOne validateValue method, it appeared that the SelectUtils.valueIsNoSelectionOption was returning true when the submitted value was 0 as an Integer object.

My noSelectionOption was the following:

```
<f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Please Select" itemValue="" />
```

After changing the itemValue to be #{null} it seems to work OK.

```
<f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Please Select" itemValue="#{null}" />
```